# How do I optimize SELECT COUNT in subquery

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have transaction table which has transaction_date, and I want to know how I many transaction already happens in every transaction excluding cancelled transaction.

Query Example

```
SELECT transaction_id, transaction_status, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction WHERE user_id = 2 
AND transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') 
AND transaction_date AND transaction_status != 'cancel') AS transaction_counter
FROM transaction WHERE user_id = 2

Result:

-------------------------------------------------------------
| transaction_id | transaction_status | transaction_counter |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1              | success            | 1                   |
| 2              | cancel             | 1                   |
| 3              | success            | 2                   |
| 4              | success            | 3                   |
| 5              | success            | 4                   |
| 6              | cancel             | 4                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this query runs very slow as it counts every rows and it tooks 5-10 minutes for thousand transactions. Any idea to optimize this query?

Comment: Won't this `transaction_date between DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date, '%Y-%m-01') and transaction_date` be always true? Also, what do you mean by - *how many transaction already happens in every transaction excluding cancelled transaction.* Are transaction nested?

Comment: The point is I want to count how many transactions happened already in that current row. As you can see on the example when transaction_id 3 happens, we already have 2 success transaction.

Comment: I don't understand how your query can return that result. The subquery isn't correlated and should always return the same result (IMHO). Can you post some sample data? or even better create an example on [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler).

Comment: I forgot to add time in that range. I fixed the example, so if the transaction happens on 2017-03-27 14:00:00, so the range should BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' and that transaction date

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query